# Voltage Regulation Techniques and BJT Usage in LT4363

Tags: bjt, zener, voltage-reference

There are instances when the input voltage is utilized to power a chip, and the maximum voltage (VCC) allowed on the chip is lower than the input voltage. In such cases, I consistently use a Zener diode as a reference voltage, connecting it to the VCC of the chip.

For instance, in the [LT4363 datasheet](https://chrome-extension://efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj/https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/4363fb.pdf), in Figure 8, it appears that the input voltage has been clamped to be under 80V for VCC (as per my interpretation). However, I am puzzled to see a BJT transistor on page 20, and I am uncertain about its intended function.

[image: figure 8]

[image: page20]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linking the [actual datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/4363fb.pdf) and/or including the title of the figure provides important clues as to the design of this circuit. The title is:

> **Overvoltage Regulator with 250V Surge Protection**

Since the normal input voltage is only 12V the value of a series resistor would have to be relatively low, meaning that the peak power dissipation with 250V in (for both the TVS and the resistor) would be high.

By adding high-voltage BJT the resistor can be relatively high value and it does not need to dissipate much power. Icc could be as much as 1.2mA so the transistor could be dissipating as much as ~230mW (250V-58V)*1.2mA, which is reasonable. You can think of it behaving as if R6 was lower by a factor of \$\beta\$ of the MPSA42.

Answer (score 1):

You need a current-limiting resistor to keep the current across the zener reasonable in breakdown.  This is less than ideal when using the zener breakdown for power supply purposes.

By putting in a BJT, now the voltage is at about a diode drop lower than the breakdown of the zener, but you don't have problems associated with high power supply output impedance.

Answer (score 1):

> *However, I am puzzled to see a BJT transistor on page 20, and I am
> uncertain about its intended function.*

Consider this: to begin activating an NPN BJT, the base voltage has to be a little higher than the emitter voltage. Anywhere from 0.5 volts to 1 volt is commonly seen.

So, if the Zener limits the voltage at the base to (say) 6 volts, then the voltage at the emitter cannot be higher than 5 volts to 5.5 volts. In your particular application the SMAJ58 **acts like** a 64 volt Zener and hence, the voltage at the emitter is limited to about 63 volts (even if \$V_{IN}\$ rises much higher).

At lower input voltages, the BJT still permits the IC to be powered.

It's called an emitter follower configuration.